# Save GIF and retain Paths - is it possible?

Tags: gif, photoshop, animated-gif

When I export a PSD as a gif, all my paths are gone (from the Paths pallet). How can I retain the paths? Can gifs even have vector paths?

Comment: You've answered your own question! :)  gif files just don't support that kind of information However, .tiff files can retain both layers, vector paths and paths.

Answer (score 1):

You can't; not with a gif - that only contains pixel data, timing, & bit of text (for copyright messages)

Tiff files can retain both layers, vector paths and paths.